# Kivy on python: Binding property to child property

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to bind a widgets' property to that of its child. I have used the "setter", as pointed out by the documentation. The parent's property is however never changed and its value remains as in the beginning (None).

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code example:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label

MESSAGE = "Checkbox active?   '{}'"

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    child_state = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(orientation="vertical", *args, **kwargs)
        self.checkbox = CheckBox()
        # Why doesn't this work?
        self.bind(child_state=self.checkbox.setter("active"))

        self.label = Label(text=MESSAGE.format(self.child_state))

        self.button = Button(text="Print properties",
                             on_release=self.print_properties)

        self.add_widget(self.checkbox)
        self.add_widget(self.label)
        self.add_widget(self.button)

    def on_child_state(self, *args):
        self.label.text = MESSAGE.format(self.child_state) # Never updated

    def print_properties(self, *args):
        print(f"child_state property {self.child_state}") # Always None
        print(f"checkbox property {self.checkbox.active}") # Changes between True/False
        print()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Your code means that when self.child_state changes, you will call self.checkbox.setter("active"). Is that what you intended? Presumably this binding is never called, because the child_state property never changes.

Comment: @inclement Thanks for your reply. From your explanation, seems like I misunderstood how the setter works. What I want is to set the value of the parent property to that of the child state. Namely every toime I click the checkbox, the value of parent.child_state correspondingly changes to True or False

Comment: @inclement So to correct syntax is: self.checkbox.bind(active=self.setter("child_state")) right?

Comment: Seems reasonable.